# getting int value from parse.com and passing to timer Android

Tags: android, string, parse-platform, timer, int

I have passed an int value as a string to parse.com (can not pass int directly to parse.com has to be in string, uploaded the number selected perfectly) and have retrieved it so i can pass it to another class to put into a timer.

retrieved with:

```
String secs = message.getString("seconds");
```

and passing to next class with:

```
intent.putExtra("seconds", secs);
```

in the second class:

```
String seconds1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("seconds"); 

// then i try to convert it back to int to pass to timer

    int s = Integer.valueOf(seconds1); 

Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
            }
        }, s);
```

passing **S** shows as null and does not work with the timer so the app does not load the activity from app. I have tried to convert the string before i pass it to this class but it also does not work.

Comment: Have you tried to print out the value of "s" in your Logcat? Is it null or not? Have you considered that s should be in milliseconds, not seconds?

Comment: Ahh yes it's in seconds should I do s *1000

Comment: Is the run() working at all (also try to print something in your logcat within run()?

Comment: run() is working fine s is in seconds not milliseconds i think that may be the issue, ill try s * 1000 and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

when you pass an int to a timer it has to be in milliseconds so you should put

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
    }, s * 1000);
```